# UICollectionView cells don't appear until swipe

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

When my view loads, nothing happens until I swipe left or right. That's when all my cells appear. I'm inheriting from a custom class called [InfiniteCollectionView](https://github.com/masoapps/infinite-uicollectionview).

Here is the code for my collection view:

```
@IBOutlet weak var infiniteCollectionView: InfiniteCollectionView! {
    didSet {

        infiniteCollectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "AchievementDetailCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        infiniteCollectionView.infiniteDataSource = self
        infiniteCollectionView.infiniteDelegate = self

        infiniteCollectionView.opaque = false
        infiniteCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        infiniteCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Below is some code so that i can overlap my collection view on top of another view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    view.opaque = false

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

extension AchievementsDetailCollectionViewController : InfiniteCollectionViewDataSource {

func numberOfItems(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
{
    return dataArray.count
}

func cellForItemAtIndexPath(collectionView: UICollectionView, dequeueIndexPath: NSIndexPath, usableIndexPath: NSIndexPath)  -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: dequeueIndexPath) as! AchievementDetailCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.95)
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = true

    return cell
}
}
```

No matter what I do, it just doesn't seem to appear until I swipe left or right. I tried reloading the data in viewDidLoad, and when I try to reloadData() in cellForRowAtIndexPath I get a crash at the method: super.layoutSubviews()

At this point I'm thinking that it probably has something to do with my constraints. Is that true, or is there an issue with my code?

EDIT: I should also mention that my collection view's data is being reloaded on the main thread.

EDIT #2: Data source methods for custom class:

```
extension InfiniteCollectionView: UICollectionViewDataSource
{
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection   section: Int) -> Int
{
    let numberOfItems = infiniteDataSource?.numberOfItems(self) ?? 0
    return  3 * numberOfItems
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    return infiniteDataSource!.cellForItemAtIndexPath(self, dequeueIndexPath: indexPath, usableIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: getCorrectedIndex(indexPath.row - indexOffset), inSection: 0))
}

private func getCorrectedIndex(indexToCorrect: Int) -> Int
{
    if let numberOfCells = infiniteDataSource?.numberOfItems(self)
    {
        if (indexToCorrect < numberOfCells && indexToCorrect >= 0)
        {
            return indexToCorrect
        }
        else
        {
            let countInIndex = Float(indexToCorrect) / Float(numberOfCells)
            let flooredValue = Int(floor(countInIndex))
            let offset = numberOfCells * flooredValue
            return indexToCorrect - offset
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0
    }
}
```

}

EDIT #3:

The first screenshot wouldn't be helpful. It's just a black screen.

Here's what I see when I swipe right on the black screen:

[image]

Comment: i think the reloadData() is happening in background queue. do you know who calls this infiniteCollectionView?

Comment: no one except my collectionviewcontroller. I should edit my question to mention it's happening in the main thread

Comment: First of all, never call `reloadData` on a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` in a `dataSource` method. Can you show your `collectionView's dataSource`?

Comment: Just updated the question to contain the dataSource

Comment: I just made the cell show without swiping by commenting out the part where I register the nib, and manually setting up the cell in the storyboard, but now none of its content is displayed...

Comment: can you share the screenshots?

Comment: Can do, will update the question